# How to call out sections of source code?

Tags: listings, code

I am using listings to display source code. I would like to label/bracket certain lines of this source code so that I can call out each section and describe what they do.

Here is an example of what I'd like to do:

[image]

Here some latex containing example code. The /**** SECTION X ****/ comments within the code are just there to denote where I'd like the sections in this particular listing.

```
    \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
List<Point2D> data = // ...

/**** SECTION A ****/
val x = scaleBand<Int> {
    rangeRound(listOf(0.0, width))
    domain(data.indices.toList())
    padding(0.1)
}

/**** SECTION B ****/
val y = scaleLinear<Double> {
  domain(listOf(height, 0))
  range(listOf(0, data.maxBy { it.y })
}

/**** SECTION C ****/
val bar = rect<Point2D> {
    width(x.bandwidth)
    height { d, _ -> height - y(d.y) }
    fill(Color.STEELBLUE)
}

/**** SECTION D ****/
val root = Group()
root.selectAll<Point2D>(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append { d, _, _ -> bar(d) }
    .translateX { _, i, _ -> x(i) }
    .translateY { d, _, _ -> y(d.y) }
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a minimal compilable example (without the nice new markup you want) so that folks here can just cut and paste to get started on an answer.

Comment: Tikzmark combine with escape inside should work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on [cmhughes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/6621/cmhughes) comment sugessting the use of `tikzmark`, and the multiline bracket solution found [here,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUzIB.png) I was able to come up with the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathreplacing}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{%
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline] \node [anchor=base] (#1) {};}

\newcommand*{\BracektStubSize}{0.5em}%
\NewDocumentCommand\LeftBracket{%
    O{}% #1 = draw options
    O{0pt}% #2 = shift to be applied (optional, for use with nested braces)
    m% #3 = top \tikzmark name
    m% #4 = bottom \tikzmark name
    m% #5 = node text
}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,baseline]
        \coordinate (Top Start of Bracket) at ([shift={(#2-15pt,5pt)}]#3.north east);
        \coordinate (Bottom Start of Bracket) at ([shift={(#2-15pt,2pt)}]#4.south east);
        \draw[thick, #1] 
            (Top Start of Bracket) --++(-\BracektStubSize,0) 
                |-(Bottom Start of Bracket) ;

        \node[xshift=-5pt, align=left, anchor=east, #1]
            at ($(Bottom Start of Bracket)!0.5!(Top Start of Bracket)$) {#5};
    \end{tikzpicture}    
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=\&]
List<Point2D> data = // ...

&\tikzmark{Mark A}&val x = scaleBand<Int> {
    rangeRound(listOf(0.0, width))
    domain(data.indices.toList())
    padding(0.1)
&\tikzmark{End A}&}


&\tikzmark{Mark B}&val y = scaleLinear<Double> {
  domain(listOf(height, 0))
  range(listOf(0, data.maxBy { it.y })
&\tikzmark{End B}&}

&\tikzmark{Mark C}&val bar = rect<Point2D> {
    width(x.bandwidth)
    height { d, _ -> height - y(d.y) }
    fill(Color.STEELBLUE)
&\tikzmark{End C}&}

&\tikzmark{Mark D}&val root = Group()
root.selectAll<Point2D>(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append { d, _, _ -> bar(d) }
    .translateX { _, i, _ -> x(i) }
&\tikzmark{End D}&    .translateY { d, _, _ -> y(d.y) }
\end{lstlisting}

\LeftBracket[black][0pt]{Mark A}{End A}{a}
\LeftBracket[black][0pt]{Mark B}{End B}{b}
\LeftBracket[black][0pt]{Mark C}{End C}{c}
\LeftBracket[black][0pt]{Mark D}{End D}{d}

\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image]

Comment: Great job! Really well done :)